# How to measure capacitance of two electrodes submerged in insulating oil?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I'm trying to work out the capacitance between two electrodes submerged in insulating oil at multiple distances.

If I have an electrodes gap of 1mm, with an oil rated to insulate at 30kV per/mm. What would my capacitance be?

If I changed it to 0.9mm, what would my capacitance be? Does it automatically reduce by 10%?, does this scale? Reduce it to 0.5mm, does the capacitance reduce by 50%?

Thanks, please comment if more details are needed.

Comment: C = k Area/gap so reducing gap increases C

Comment: How long is a piece of string. If you researched what the capacitance formula is you'd see it depends on 3 other factors (ignoring cable feed length). If you increased the gap to 100 metres, would capacitance grow by 100,000 times? Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: Don't forget to account for the container holding the oil. If the walls of the container are conductive (like a metal can) then they'll influence the capacitance between your probes.

Answer (score 2):

For large flat plates, the capacitance is *inversely* proportional to the distance between the plates. So, it the distance is halved, the capacitance will be twice as much.

If your electrodes are not plates, but rods, the formula is more complicated.

http://eguruchela.com/physics/calculator/Capacitance-of-Parallel-Cylinders-Calculator.php

This formula assumes a vacuum. For oil, you would need to multiply by the relative permittivity of oil, about 2 or so. Not sure why they are using mu for permittivity instead of epsilon.